# dynamic validation isnt work in vuelidate

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

I want returns password and password confirm validation only if the user wants to change the password.

```
    validations() {
      if(this.changePassword) {
        return {
          editedItem : {
            account_id : {
              required,
              minLength : minLength(4),
              maxLength : maxLength(15)
            },
            name: { 
              required,
              minLength: minLength(4),
              maxLength: maxLength(20) 
            },
            password: { 
              required,
              minLength: minLength(4),
              maxLength: maxLength(20) 
            },
            passwordConfirm: { 
              required,
              sameAsPassword: sameAs('password')
            }
          }
        }
      }

      else {
        return {
          editedItem : {
            account_id : {
              required,
              minLength : minLength(4),
              maxLength : maxLength(15)
            },
            name: { 
              required,
              minLength: minLength(4),
              maxLength: maxLength(20) 
            },
          }
        }
      }
    },
    computed: {
      accountIdErrors () {
        const errors = []
        if (!this.$v.editedItem.account_id.$dirty) return errors
        !this.$v.editedItem.account_id.minLength && errors.push('ID should be 4 to 15 characters')
        !this.$v.editedItem.account_id.maxLength && errors.push('ID should be 4 to 15 characters')
        !this.$v.editedItem.account_id.required && errors.push('ID required')
        return errors
      },
      nameErrors () {
        const errors = []
        if (!this.$v.editedItem.name.$dirty) return errors
        !this.$v.editedItem.name.minLength && errors.push('Name should be 4 to 20 characters')
        !this.$v.editedItem.name.maxLength && errors.push('Name should be 4 to 20 characters')
        !this.$v.editedItem.name.required && errors.push('Name required')
        return errors
      },
      pwErrors () {
        const errors = []
        if (!this.$v.editedItem.password.$dirty) return errors
        !this.$v.editedItem.password.minLength && errors.push('Password should be 4 to 20 characters')
        !this.$v.editedItem.password.maxLength && errors.push('Password should be 4 to 20 characters')
        !this.$v.editedItem.password.required && errors.push('Password required')
        return errors
      },
      pwConfirmErrors() {
        const errors = []
        if (!this.$v.editedItem.passwordConfirm.$dirty) return errors
        !this.$v.editedItem.passwordConfirm.sameAsPassword && errors.push('Not same as password')
        return errors
      },
     }
```

Below is the form. The "changePassword" variable depends on the v-switch.

```
        <v-dialog
          v-model="editDialog"
          max-width="500px"
        >

          <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
              <span class="text-h5"> Edit Account </span>
            </v-card-title>

            <v-card-text>
              <v-container>
                <v-form>

                  <v-row>
                    <v-text-field
                        :disabled="!createMode"
                        v-model="editedItem.account_id"
                        :error-messages="accountIdErrors"
                        label="Account ID"
                        hide-details="auto"
  
                        @input="$v.editedItem.account_id.$touch()"
                        @blur="$v.editedItem.account_id.$touch()"
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-row>

                  <v-row>
                    <v-text-field
                      v-model="editedItem.name"
                      :error-messages="nameErrors"
                      label="Name"
                      hide-details="auto"

                      @input="$v.editedItem.name.$touch()"
                      @blur="$v.editedItem.name.$touch()"
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-row>

                  <v-row>

                    <v-col>
                      //if the "changePassword" becomes true, password validation should be enabled
                      <v-switch
                        :disabled="createMode"
                        v-model="changePassword"
                        label="Change Password"
                        @click="editPwclear"
                      ></v-switch>

                      <v-text-field
                          v-if="changePassword"
                          v-model="editedItem.password"
                          :error-messages="pwErrors"
                          label="New Password"
                          hide-details="auto"
                          type = "password"

                          @input="$v.editedItem.password.$touch()"
                          @blur="$v.editedItem.password.$touch()"
                      ></v-text-field>
  
                      <v-text-field
                          v-if="changePassword"
                          v-model="editedItem.passwordConfirm"
                          :error-messages="pwConfirmErrors"
                          label="Confirm Password"
                          hide-details="auto"
                          type = "password"
  
                          @input="$v.editedItem.passwordConfirm.$touch()"
                          @blur="$v.editedItem.passwordConfirm.$touch()"
                      ></v-text-field>
                    </v-col>

                  </v-row>  

                </v-form>
              </v-container>
            </v-card-text>

            <v-card-actions>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn
                color="blue darken-1"
                text
                @click="close"
              >
                Cancle
              </v-btn>
              <v-btn
                color="blue darken-1"
                text
                @click="editSubmit"
              >
               Save
              </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>

        </v-dialog>
```

editPwclear() that runs when the v-switch is clicked. Initializes the value to an empty value.

```
      editPwclear(){
        this.editedItem.password = ''
        this.editedItem.passwordConfirm = ''
        this.$v.$reset()
      },
```

Even if I enter the correct value, a length error always occurs.

Comment: what fields are giving the errors?

Comment: Password fields give an error. I checked again and it seems that the first error remains the same. If i enter only 2 characters and the minLength error occurs, the error remains even if i enter more than 4 characters again.

Comment: You may need to reset the validations() after the switch is changed. Maybe they are set on setup or mounted.

Comment: @click="editPwclear" is on the switch. there's **this$v.reset()** in the **editPwclear()** **this.$v.editedItem.$reset()** also does not work :(